# Saving excel worksheet as .txt

Tags: excel, vba

I'm newbie in VBA.Soo I have a task where I should save excel worksheet with 1 specific row in .txt format.

At this moment I only know how to save it in specific direction (for example desktop).

But is there a way for the user to choose with poping out window (like as save as) where excatly he wants to save it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim fso As Object

strPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\"
strFolderName = "Atskaites"
strFullPath = strPath & strFolderName & "\"

If Dir(strPath & strFolderName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strFullPath
End If

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'teksta faila izveidosana
Dim Fileout As Object
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(strFullPath & TextBox1.Text & ".txt", True, True)  'kur izveidot un kada formata    Fileout.Visible = True

Fileout.WriteLine "Klients:"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox1.Text)
Fileout.WriteLine "06.17"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox2.Text)
Fileout.WriteLine "07.17"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox3.Text)
Fileout.WriteLine "08.17"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox4.Text)
Fileout.WriteLine "09.17"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox5.Text)
Fileout.WriteLine "10.17"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox6.Text)
Fileout.WriteLine "Kopa"
Fileout.WriteLine (TextBox7.Text)

MsgBox ("Saved")

Fileout.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The sample code below is just one way. Since you say you want to save a row of data, it first asks you to choose the row, then asks for what directory you want to save it in, it then copies that row to a new workbook, and finally saves that workbook as a text file in that directory.

Of course, you need to modify it for your particular situation. This is just to get you started with something that works.

```
Option Explicit
Sub saveRow()
Dim theDir As String
Dim sh As Worksheet, wk As Workbook, r As Range
Set r = Application.InputBox("select the row to export", , , Type:=8)
theDir = folderFromUser("C:/") 'C: is just the default location
Set wk = Workbooks.Add
r.Worksheet.Rows(r.row).Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
wk.SaveAs theDir & "\test.txt", XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wk.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function folderFromUser(initialPath As String) As String
Dim fd As FileDialog, ButtonClickedByUser As Boolean, msg As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'see also msoFileDialogFilePicker
  fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
  fd.InitialFileName = Left(initialPath, InStrRev(initialPath, "\"))
  ButtonClickedByUser = fd.Show
  If ButtonClickedByUser = False Then Exit Function
  folderFromUser = fd.SelectedItems(1)
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) _
  & Err.Description, , "Error in folderFromUser routine", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
Err.Clear
End Function
```